# Check Street View Available or Not

Tags: android, google-maps, google-street-view

First of all, I want to get lat-long from the user and then showing the street view map in my app, so my question is when user enter lat-long there is any method to **identify** that this lat-long is **supporting street view map** or **not**

I don't find any solution that can check whether this **lat-long support** for **street view map** or not.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35824786

Comment: so this is not possible!

Comment: did u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218672/how-to-check-if-position-if-valid-in-streetview-in-android/25438088#25438088

Comment: yes this one i know, i need identify wihout street view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218672/how-to-check-if-position-if-valid-in-streetview-in-android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675032/how-to-check-if-google-street-view-available-and-display-message

Comment: What edit i am not getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess using street view image metadata you can get those details.

Here is a link i found about [street view image metadata](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata)

There you can see different [status codes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata#status-codes)

Example Request :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?size=600x300&location=78.648401,14.194336&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Example Response :

```
{
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Comment: @MohitSuthar Glad to help you :)